# ¿Existe búsqueda insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas para mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Para `postgres` se trabaja fácilmente con `ILIKE` pero para `mysql` no encuentro, lo único que consigo es casos como este:

`SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE LOWER(<key>) LIKE LOWER('%<searchpattern>%')`

Haciendo así todos los resultados de la columna y el valor consultado minúscula. Hay una manera mas simple o etiqueta para `mysql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes indicar el `COLLATE` a utilizar en la sentencia. No tendrías más que indicar un `COLLATE`case insensitive. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  * FROM  table WHERE key COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%searchpattern%'
```

También puedes establecer el COLLATE de la columna como case insensitive de forma que no necesites indicarlo en la sentencia. Por ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY COLUMN key VARCHAR(…) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
```

Comment: ¿Cual es mas ético? ¿esta manera o indicando el `BINARY` en el `WHERE`?

Comment: @PabloContreras El Binary si que hace la diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Creo que eso no es lo que buscas.

Comment: Creo que te contradices en tu comentario o no lo entendí bien.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera muy simple:

```
SELECT *  FROM `tabla` WHERE BINARY `columna` = 'valor'
```

Con la palabra clave *Binary* buscarás exactamente esa palabra.

Comment: ¿Cual es mas ético? ¿esta manera o indicando el `COLLATE`?

Comment: @PabloContreras La verdad, no sé qué hace collate, pero binary compara la cadena carácter a carácter.