# búsqueda insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas COLLATE vs BINARY

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Anteriormente hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76856/existe-b%C3%BAsqueda-insensible-a-may%C3%BAsculas-y-min%C3%BAsculas-para-mysql). Pero no quedo claro cual es mejor, o el ¿Por que? de cada uno.

El `COLLATE` se modifica la columna y simplemente se ahorra el código en el `sql`, pero el `BINARY`

Supongo que afecta en cuanto a velocidad o carga de procesos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Son dos cosas distintas.

1. El COLLATE define entre otras cosas si una columna va a ser sensible
   a Mayúsculas o mínusculas, esta configuración va a durar por siempre
   en esa tabla/columna (a menos obviamente que la vuelvas a
   modificar). Dependiendo de la naturaleza de los datos puede ser
   importante que sea de una forma u otra. En general es más habitual
   que los campos que referencien a nombres sean insensibles, de forma
   tal que un búsqueda simple tipo `LIKE '%ALBERTO%'` permita recuperar
   `'Alberto'`, `'alberto'` o incluso `'aLBERTO'`. ¿Cuando podríamos necesitar
   un campo "sensible"? depende del dato, tal vez nos encontremos con
   algún código que requiera combinaciones de mayúsculas y minúsculas,
   no es lo más común pero sin duda hay casos.
2. El `BINARY` es un operador, que en la cláusula `WHERE` permite,
   sobre un campo insensible a mayúsculas / minúsculas, "forzar" una
   comparación exacta. por ejemplo, si en el ejemplo anterior
   quisiéramos buscar solo los `'Alberto'` y no los `'alberto'`,
   `'ALBERTO'`, etc. podemos forzar   la búsqueda exacta mediante el
   `BINARY`

Comment: ok gracias amigo.